# dim. of $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta_{n}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I want to find dim. $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta_{n}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]$ for positive rational number $a$ and $n^\text{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_{n}$ with assumption $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=n$. I already know $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{n}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=\varphi\left(n\right)$, but not  $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta_{n}\right):\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)\right]$ nor $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta_{n}\right):\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{n}\right)\right]$.

How can find dim. $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta_{n}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]$?

Comment: Suppose $a \neq 1$. Can you write the $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a})$-minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$?

Comment: I think I should factorize cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{n}$ in $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)$. But, I can't. Could you give me more hints?

Comment: Do you know what the intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ look like? Are any contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a})$?

Comment: No, there are no information about intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{n}\right)$ which contained in $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)$.

I think we should splitt some cases.(Someone said to me, dim. is $n\varphi\left(n\right)$ or its half.)